# Fill observation from latest year in grouped data using data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

For each id, I am trying to fill the value in the code column corresponding to the latest year using data.table.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  year=c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2015, 2016, NA, NA, 2016),
  code=c(1,2,2, 1,2,3, 3,4,5)
)

> df
  id year code
1  1 2014    1
2  1 2015    2
3  1 2016    2
4  2 2015    1
5  2 2015    2
6  2 2016    3
7  3   NA    3
8  3   NA    4
9  3 2016    5
```

In dplyr:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(code2=last(na.omit(code[order(year, na.last=F)])))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
     id  year  code code2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2014     1     2
2     1  2015     2     2
3     1  2016     2     2
4     2  2015     1     3
5     2  2015     2     3
6     2  2016     3     3
7     3    NA     3     5
8     3    NA     4     5
9     3  2016     5     5
```

Attempt in data.table:

```
df %>%
  as.data.table() %>%
  .[,code2:=last(na.omit(code[order(year, na.last=F)]), by=id)] %>%
  as.data.table()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `data.table` like below

```
> setDT(df)[,code2:=code[which.max(year)],id][]
   id year code code2
1:  1 2014    1     2
2:  1 2015    2     2
3:  1 2016    2     2
4:  2 2015    1     3
5:  2 2015    2     3
6:  2 2016    3     3
7:  3   NA    3     5
8:  3   NA    4     5
9:  3 2016    5     5
```